# Vulnerabilities found in "activejob" and "activestorage" gems. Method of update not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-activejob, rails-activestorage

I have an error saying I have a vulnerability and I need to update `activejob` and `activestorage` to `>= 5.2.1.1` in my rails application

So in my `Gemfile` I have

```
gem 'activejob', '<= 5.2.1.1'
gem 'activestorage', '<= 5.2.1.1'
```

And I ran

```
bundle update activejob
bundle update activestorage
```

I used `<=` because I have some dependencies that rely on an older version of `activejob` and `activestorage`. It doesn't work with the `5.2.1.1` version. And I'm unable to update those gems because it can cause my application to break at this time.

When I ran `bundle audit --update` it still says that I have the same vulnerabilities and that I should upgrade.

After running `bundle install` this is what I have in my `Gemfile.lock`

```
GEM
  specs:
    activejob (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activestorage (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)

DEPENDENCIES
  activejob (<= 5.2.1.1)
  activestorage (<= 5.2.1.1)
```

I can't delete my `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`. I also can't run `bundle update` because I have gems that I don't want to update. It can break the application. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveJob and ActiveSupport are dependent on your rails version.

If your rails (or any other gem that places limitations on AJ and AS for that matter) version (perhaps 5.0) is locked down and is constraining the versions  of ActiveJob and ActiveStorage, then it will override your version requirements set in your gemfile for those two gems.

I'd hazard a guess that you need to update rails to 5.1 and bundle update, but it's hard to say without seeing your full gemfile/gemfile.lock

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right. The solution is to update rails which I was trying not to because I was afraid it was going to break the application. It might still break it but I'll just have to go in and fix things. :)

Comment: Naught to do but try (I had to bump ransacker to 2.x from 1.8.8 to support Rails 5.1 too - if you use that). Good luck!